# I can not connect to SMB shares after upgrading Macos from mojave to catalina

Tags: smb, macos-catalina

Before upgrade, I used CMD+K to connect an SMB share. 
I has upgraded Macos from mojave to catalina yesterday. When I use CMD+K to connect that SMB share, it can not working. 
Dose new Macos disabled SMB? Help me please, it has decreasesed my work efficiency.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [apple.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it in a strange way, 
As we are all aware Mac user has actually 2 names: one is the username (the profile name if i may) and the Display name.

Prior to Catalina , when authenticating with an SMB share from a Windows computer , I was using the display name (although it is a full name with a space) and everything was cool.

In Catalina , I found out I can only use the username, windows cannot authenticate with the display name.

of course , before I got to this point I have checked/enabled SMBv2, created the NetBios file in the MAC and all the other hints I could find, which obviously did not do the trick for me.

hope this helps